# What does the following ADF test in R signify?

Tags: r, time-series, interpretation, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

While checking for stationarity of differences (first difference) data using ADF test in R, I get that the test statistic is significant for all the deterministic regressors - "none", "drift", "trend". Does this imply my data has both trend and drift? The following is the output that I got from R:

**ADF test for "None"**

```
data:  ddata ~ .
ADF(1) = -6.8066, p-value = 1.657e-12
alternative hypothesis: true delta is less than 0
sample estimates:
     delta 
-0.9144679
```

**ADF test for "Drift"**

```
data:  ddata ~ .
ADF(1) = -6.7765, p-value = 3.6e-08
alternative hypothesis: true delta is less than 0
sample estimates:
     delta 
-0.9152028
```

**ADF test for "Trend"**

```
data:  ddata ~ .
ADF(1) = -6.7621, p-value = 4.075e-07
alternative hypothesis: true delta is less than 0
sample estimates:
     delta 
-0.9185305
```